# waht is the best way to pass array from jquery ajax call to servlet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

i am passing my arrays like this.but when i am retriving in servlet it is giving nullpointer execption?is this best way to do it ?if no please tell me how can i do much better?
here my .js file

```
 var selected4 = new Array();
    var selected3 = new Array();
    var selected2 = new Array(); 
    var selected1 = new Array();
i am pushing the values into arrays.my ajax call is like this.       
    var value3
    =domains:selected1,accounts:selected2,categories:selected3,projectType:selected4};
     $.ajax({
                url: "CategoryReport",
                //type: "post",
                data: value3,
                dataType:'JSON',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {}});
my servlet code is
    String[] domains = request.getParameterValues("domains");
    for(int i=0;i<domains.length;i++){
            System.out.println("domains"+domains[i]);
        }
```

iam getting null values for domains.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using rails?
I come from the .NET world. Being that said, when we want to send an array to a controller we do this,

```
$.ajax({
url: "CategoryReport",
                type: "post",
                data: JSON.stringify({ list: value3 }),
                dataType:'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {}});
});
```

which willbe passed to the server as a querystring like

```
list=project1&list=project2&list=project3...
```

which then you can capture in a `String[] list or List<string> list`

i hope it helps.

Comment: how can i send more than one list?
data:JSON.stringify({domains:selected1,accounts:selected2,categories:selected3,projectType:selected4})

Comment: i am getting nullpointer exception if isend data like this    data:JSON.stringify({domains:selected1,accounts:selected2,categories:selected3,p‌​rojectType:selected4})

Comment: hmm, it's correct. Did you check your server side code whether your request.getParameterValues accepting with exact names? Inorder to receive accounts, you must say request.getParameterValues("accounts") and so for the others.